# functions in form of $f\circ g$

Tags: functions

Express the function in the form $f\circ g$. (Use non-identity functions for $f$ and $g$.)
$F(x)=(6x+x^2)^4$
I understand you have to find what each $f(x)$ equals and $g(x)$ equals but not really sure where to begin. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=x^4$$ and $$g(x)=6x+x^2$$ then $$(f\circ g)(x)=f(g(x))=f(6x+x^2)=(6x+x^2)^4=F(x)$$
of course there's infintely many ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

$f_1(x)=x^{4n}, \quad g_1(x)=(6x+x^2)^{1/n} \implies f_1 \circ g_1 = F, \ \forall n\neq0$

or

$f_2(x)=nx, \quad g_2(x)=\frac{1}{n}(6x+x^2)^4 \implies f_2 \circ g_2 = F, \ \forall n\neq0$